# Pass '{}' as parameter to format string in function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have one string that is build based on some parameter as following. What is the best way for me to do it so I can build the string based on parameter and when I pass argument, I do not need to use `xxxx{}xxx{}.format('{}', '{}')`

```
def func(_st, **kwargs):
    if 'b' in kwargs:
        return _st.format(kwargs['b'], 'c')
    if 'c' in kwargs:
        return _st.format('b', kwargs['c'])

_var = 'sss'
_sA = func('aaa{}/bb{}/cc{}'.format(_var, '{}', '{}'), b=1)
_sC = func('aaa{}/bb{}/cc{}'.format(_var, '{}', '{}'), c=3)
print(_sA)
print(_sC)
##
_sA = aaasss/bb1/ccc
_sB = aaasss/bbb/cc3
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have `{}` in the output from `format()`?

Comment: for string ```func('aaa{}/bb{}/cc{}'.format(_var, '{}', '{}'), b=1)```. i need to pass {} as parameter so i can use format in the method func to format string again.. do i have a better way to do it?